# wlan0 not showing in Kali

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I tried to install **compact-wireless-2010-10-26-p** to resolve wlan0 issue under Kali 2.0 (VM) but encountered with the error shown in below screenshot:
[image]

Videos available to resolve the issue show no error while executing ***make load*** command.
Please help.

Thanks,
Satish

Comment: I think there is no way to install internal wifi card inside VM. 
Please find the details in below link:

http://superuser.com/questions/709519/how-to-detect-internal-wifi-card-as-physical-device-instead-virtual-ethernet-dev